# SpringBootServletInitializer causes whitelabel error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm going through this online course about Spring MVC.
During the course the instructor is adding a simple controller, and a simple jsp page.
In addition the application class is extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

my index.html file is found in `src/main/webapp` and my jsp file is found in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`
I've also added `spring.mvc.view.prefix/suffix` accordingly.

for some reason when i get to this point at the course, extending the `SpringBootServletInitializer` is causing whitelabel error to my main view (index.html) but the path to jsp file is working just fine.

I've tried some suggestions as changing `@Controller` to `@RestController` or removing the `SpringBootServletInitializer` but it didn't work (removing the `SpringBootServletInitializer` caused 404 when looking for the jsp page).

here is my code:

*pom.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pluralSight</groupId>
    <artifactId>conference</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>conference</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

*controller:*

```
package com.pluralSight.conference.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("greeting")
    public String greeting(Map<String, Object> model){
        model.put("message","Hello Daniel");
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

*application class:*

```
package com.pluralSight.conference;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConferenceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConferenceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

*application.properties:*

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: @dariosicily Hi, packaging as a war.

Comment: Thank you ,  I tried your code putting a `index.jsp` page in the `webapp` folder and it worked when I tried to access `myapplication` and your controller works fine when I tried to access `myapplication/greeting`, is this your expected result ?

Comment: @dariosicily This is the expected result. The only difference is probably I'm using `index.html` instead of `index.jsp`. I'll try replacing to jsp and will update

Comment: @dariosicily It worked. Thanks! But now I'm really interested in WHY. does the SpringBootServletInitializer only look for jsp files in the webapp directory? Shouldn't HTML file work too?

Comment: Because of the line `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` that tells to your application to look just only jsp pages, so excluding the html pages.

Comment: @dariosicily I figured it's something like that as well, but it doesn't work with html file also without these lines in `application.properties` and with jsp it does work.  And there's also `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/` so I strongly believe that this is not the reason.

Comment: I am also curious as to why but glad I found an answer